# Angular ngx-swiper-wrapper arrow style change

Tags: css, angular, web, sass, swiper.js

I previously created a swiper (ngx-swiper-wrapper) and I changed the color of the arrows the following way:

```
::ng-deep.swiper-button-next::after, ::ng-deep.swiper-button-prev::after {
      color: $primary-light;
}
```

Now I created another one on a different page where the color should be black. The problem is when I visit the page with the first swiper and then I navigate to the other page with the second swiper, the color stays the white.

Is there a better way to change the color or a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've been running into the same issue, and spent days looking for a better solution, till i found one, it works just fine, no need to change the svg image or somthing just add the code below into your css file :

```
::ng-deep .swiper-button-next,
 ::ng-deep .swiper-button-prev {

    color: #207868 !important;
}

:root {
    --swiper-theme-color: #207868 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and changed a few things and it's working:

```
::ng-deep .swiper{

    .swiper-button-next::after,
    .swiper-button-next::after{
         color: #207868;
         or
      --swiper-theme-color: #207868;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular, then do this

```
 ::ng-deep { 
     :root {
         --swiper-theme-color: #cd0000
     }
 }
```